# control double pointer on array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, function-calls, double-pointer

I need to print a name for pointer.
But it doesn't works at all. Console stops..

Maybe the problem will be on 'find_young' function.
I don't know what's the problem and how to fix it. 
What can I do for a right code.

Below are my codes.

========

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int age; 
} PERSON;

PERSON s[3] = { {"ACE", 25}, {"HEART" ,28}, {"CLOVER", 40} };

void find_young(PERSON **p) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (s[i].age > s[i+1].age) {
            p = &s[i+1];
        }
    }
};

void Ex1()
{   
    struct PERSON *p;
    p = &s[0];

    find_young(&p);
    printf("youngest man is %s.", p->name);
}
```

Comment: That code should not compile. There is no `struct PERSON`, only `typedef PERSON` of anonymous structure type. Thus `struct PERSON *p;` should be `PERSON *p;`

Comment: 1) `i < 1` It is not possible to check all of the elements. 2) `s[i].age > s[i+1].age` Conditions are insufficient

Comment: @punit Do not change the problems of the post code.

Comment: Sorry . Is there any way to revert it. I am happy to do it :-)

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  Even this short posted code causes the compiler to output 8 warnings and 1 error.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: this line: `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {` will only look at the first element in the array.

Comment: this line: `if (s[i].age > s[i+1].age) {` will only compare successive elements in the array, it should be comparing the currently found lowest age with the currently being tested element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning between wrong types, and the compiler should warn you about it:

```
p = &s[i + 1];
```

Here the expression `&s[i + 1]` is a pointer to `PERSON`, but `p` is a pointer *to a pointer* to `PERSON`. Not quite the same thing.

What you want is

```
*p = &s[i + 1];
```

Comment: note that this loop needs further improvement: it does not correctly find the youngest, and it's also poor design to rely on the caller to set the value in some cases

Comment: @윤성필 Then you should accept the answer to indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

struct PERSON is wrong , you have already used typedef so no need to use struct . Just use PERSON *p. 
To find the youngest , you code should be as follow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct {
        char *name;
        int age; 
    } PERSON;

    PERSON s[3] = { {"ACE", 100}, {"HEART" ,28}, {"CLOVER", 40} };

    void find_young(PERSON **p) {
        int i;
       for (i = 0; i < ((sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]) -1); i++) { 
            if (*(p)->age > s[i+1].age) { 
                  *p = &s[i+1]; 
            } 
       } 

    };

    void Ex1()
    {   
        PERSON *p;
        p = s;

        find_young(&p);
        printf("youngest man is %s.", p->name);
    }
int main()
{
Ex1();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: the `for()` loop fails to work correctly for certain ordering of the age fields. suggest: `for (i = 0; i < ((sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]) -1); i++) {
            if (*(p)->age > s[i+1].age) {
                *p = &s[i+1];
            } }

Comment: Updated the answer as per your suggestion :-)